# useRef function doesn't working inside then of axios

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I want to create dynamic inputs for OTP login. but my `useRef` doesn't created.

```
 //axios
  api.post('auth/login', { mobile:_mobile}).then((res: any) => {
   for(var i = 0 ; i < res.digits ; ++i){
     inputs.push(i)
   }
   console.log("inputs",inputs)
   inputRef = inputs.map(x => useRef(null));
   console.log("inputRef",inputRef) //it doesn't called
   
   var now = new Date();
   now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + ( parseInt(res.expired_at)/60));
   setExpiredAt(now.getTime())
   showLoading(false);
   toggleVerification(true);
 }).catch(() => {
   showLoading(false)
 })
```

it doesn't called:

```
 console.log("inputRef",inputRef)
```

Comment: That's unfortunately entirely incorrect use of useRef - you can't use hooks in a handler, and you can't loop them like that. What is your end goal here?

Comment: number of my input's coming of server. (inputs is dynamic). how can handle this senario?

Comment: How you'd handle anything dynamic - with an array and a map call.

Comment: _"number of my input's coming of server"_ - So you want to count the number of inputs you get from the API call? It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve.